# Code First Circular Reference Foreign Key Configuration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

The following code creates foreign key errors when all code is not commented.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FavoriteChildId { get; set; }
    public Child FavoriteChild { get; set; }
    //public int WorstChildId { get; set; }
    public Child WorstChild { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class CFContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

It works if the foreign key names aren't specified but then there's no way to edit the models.  Does anyone know how to specify the foreign key names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the naming convention will create the proper FK's above - your code:

```
public int WorstChildId { get; set; }
public Child WorstChild { get; set; }
```

Does create the FK of WorstChildId for WorstChild.  However, when I tried the code you had above, I got a multiple delete path error (Parent -> WorstChild -> ChildTable, Parent -> FavoriteChild -> ChildTable)

You can set either one, or both of your mappings to not cascade on delete, and that will fix your problem:

```
public class CFContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Parent)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(p => p.WorstChild)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
         .HasRequired(c => c.Parent)
         .WithRequiredPrincipal(p => p.FavoriteChild)
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark, your solution worked great for the above example.  Unfortunately, I require a 3rd parent-child reference which doesn't seem to work.  If you have a moment, please check out my latest question, which contains the problem code. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062202/code-first-foreign-key-configuration)